# Using value from an existing cell inside a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the "Camera" feature in excel 2010.

My goal is to have a cell which would have a date that I can manually enter and just below it the formula would get the updated value which represents the name of the sheet inside another excel file and shows me the updated screenshot.

For example:
Cell `A1` has: `12.25`

Just below it, I have: 
`='C:\My_Excel_Files\[excelDataFile.xlsx]12.25'!$A$1:$D$20`

So if I were to change the value of Cell `A1` to `12.26` the formula would pick that up automatically.

I tried using the indirect function like this: 
`='C:\My_Excel_Files\[excelDataFile.xlsx]INDIRECT(A1)'!$A$1:$D$20`

but it didn't work.

Comment: In one place you say A1's value is `12.25` but in another place you use a colon instead of a decimal point (like a time reference - `12:26`). Is this a typo in the question, or part of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @normalocity Sorry about that. It was a typo. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: `INDIRECT` doesnt work on closed workbooks, see this [comprehensive post including workarounds at Daily Dose of Excel](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/01/indirect-and-closed-workbooks/). I am a little confused on your question, do you wish to see the range of a closed workbook shown by the camera tool?

Comment: @brettdj My question isn't really about the INDIRECT function. I was just using that as an example. I wish to see the range (A1:D20) in a specific tab within the file. The tab's name would be pulled from cell which I can define (in this case A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [on this forum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/excel-using-a-variable-to-link-to-an-external-workbook-72872.html) and [this website](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/01/indirect-and-closed-workbooks/), you can use the free MOREFUNC.XLL add-in.  It provides the INDIRECT.EXT function that will do exactly what you're requesting.  The formula you need in your case would be along the lines of:

`=INDIRECT.EXT("'C:\My_Excel_Files\[excelDataFile.xlsx]" & A1 & "'!$A$1:$D$20")`

Where you concatinate the value of A1 in the middle of the string.

Note: the links in those sites seem to not always work, you can either google for "MOREFUNC download" or try one of these links:

http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/3000-2077_4-10423159.html
http://www.freewarefiles.com/Morefunc_program_14922.html

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach might work for you. Let's assume that:

1. the Camera image object is called `MyCameraImage`
2. the "other" workbook is called `SO09.xlsm`
3. the range your image corrresponds to is `$F$1:$I$5` and is the same on all relevant sheets
4. the cell you type the date into (in the worksheet with the camera image) is `A1`

Add a `Worksheet_Change` event to the worksheet with the camera image

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wbOther As Workbook
    Dim wsOther As Worksheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.[A1]) Is Nothing Then
        Set wbOther = Workbooks("SO09.xlsm")
        On Error GoTo EH
        Set wsOther = wbOther.Worksheets(CStr([A1]))
        Me.Shapes("MyCameraImage").DrawingObject.Formula = "='[" & wbOther.Name & "]" & [A1] & "'!$F$1:$I$5"
EH:
    End If

End Sub
```

This will update the Camera Image reference to the sheet named in cell `A1` (if it exists)
Note that the "other" workbook must be open for this to work and for the image to update

Comment: That didn't work for me. Maybe I am trying something wrong. Any chance you can attach an excel file with the example so I can see what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, this is pretty straightforward. create two xlsx documents, let's call them **s1.xlsx** and **s2.xlsx**. it's from **s1** that we want to create the Camera, but the data is in **s2**.

### in s2

- with both sheets open, create what you want in **s2**. then select it
  all and press the "copy" button.

### in s1

- then go back to **s1** and wherever you want to put it, select the
  top left cell of what you'll be pasting.
- then go to the paste button, but click it's dropdown. the second icon
  will be a chain link and if you hover it says "paste link". do that.
- then select all your data you want (including the pasted link
  cell(s)) and press the camera button (assuming you've added it to
  your QAT). then select where you want to put your camera screenshot
  on s1 anywhere and click there. the screen shot will be created.
- (*Note*: the pasted link will look something like
  `=Excel.Sheet.12|'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\s2.xlsx'!'!Sheet1!R3C1:R4C2'`)

### in s2

- then go back to **s2** and change any of the values there in the
  linked cell(s)

### in s1

- you'll see the values reflected in the screen shot in **s1**
  immediately.